# How to create multiple CSV file by using FasterCSV in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, export-to-csv, fastercsv

I am very new to ruby. I have a question that how can I export two files within one click.

In the exsiting version, I can generate only one file at a time by calling 'def stream_csv', but when I try to call it twice in order to get two files, I got an error indicating about "ActionController::DoubleRenderError (Can only render or redirect once per action):" I guess, it is because of render.

Here is the source code of stream_csv:

```
def stream_csv
    require 'fastercsv'

        filename = params[:action] + ".csv"

        #this is required if you want this to work with IE      
        if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /msie/i
            headers['Pragma'] = 'public'
            headers["Content-type"] = "text/plain"
            headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
            headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
            headers['Expires'] = "0"
        else
            headers["Content-Type"] ||= 'text/csv'
            headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"#{filename}\""
            controller.response.headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "binary"
        end

        render :text => Proc.new { |response, output|
            csv = FasterCSV.new(output, :row_sep => "\r\n")
            yield csv
        }
    end
end
```

Is it possible to create two files under one click? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it's because of `render`. When you're setting `headers`, and then finally call `render`, you're building up an HTTP response to be sent to the browser. You can't do this twice from one HTTP request, which is why you get the `ActionController::DoubleRenderError`.

One way to send multiple `.csv` files at once is to combine them into a single `.zip` file and send *that* instead of the raw `.csv` files. There is an excellent, very easy to use **[`rubyzip` gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip)** you can use to build your `.zip` file.

Instead of calling render inside `stream_csv`, you can simply return the `FasterCSV` instance itself or it's String output. From the calling method you can build up a .zip file *(I'm not including code for that here since I'd just be copying and pasting from the `README` at the gem above)*.

Finally, instead of setting so many headers to force the download, take a look at Rails **[`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file)** method

Comment: Thanks for your help that contains very clear explaination :)

Comment: Glad to help, and good for you for sorting the code out on your own.